# How to delete added Shortcuts in Swift?

Tags: swift, siri, sirishortcuts

In my app I have implemented Siri Shortcuts. The user has the ability to add the Shortcut with a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` this presents a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`. This works perfekt. The user can add and edit the Shortcut with the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton`. But how I delete the Shortcut programmatically? This should happen when the user deletes the action which should be executed with this Shortcut.

This is my code to show the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`:

```
    let videoReturnIntent = VideoShortcutIntent()
    videoReturnIntent.videoID = informationToShowDetail.videoID!
    videoReturnIntent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Test"
    videoShortCutIntent = videoReturnIntent

    if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: videoReturnIntent) {
        let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        viewController.delegate = self // Object conforming to `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate`.
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Just saying, I would not want an app to be able to delete a shortcut I created. At most, to suggest me to do so, and link me to the Settings app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user already added a shortcut to Siri, you can not programmatically remove it, but the user has to remove it manually as stated here (Paragraph: Remove donations with corresponding data):

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sirikit/overview/siri-shortcuts/

If you want to delete donations, which have instead not yet been added to Siri, you can execute `INInteraction.deleteAll`. Please check the documentation for more details to this function here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/ininteraction

Comment: but this way you are removing all the donations what if you want to remove specific donations?! There are other methods under INInteraction to delete donations for a specific groupidentifier... but it is not clear how to setup this groupidentifier from a shortcut.

Comment: Sorry, I did only use the deleteAll function until now so I have no specific solution for your case.